# Rails with mutex on class variable, rake task and cron

Tags: ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-3

Sorry for such a big question.  I do not have much experience with Rails `threads` and `mutex`.

I have a class as follow which is used by different controllers to get the license for each customers.

Customers and their licenses gets added and removed every hour.  An api is available to get all customers and their licenses.

I plan to create a rake task to call `update_set_customers_licenses`, run hourly via a `cronjob`.

I have following questions:

1) Even with a `mutex`, currently there is a potential for problem, there is a chance that my rake task can occur while updating.  Any idea on how to solve this?

2) My design below writes the `json` out to a file, this is done is for safety as the api is not that reliable.  As can be seen, it is not reading the file back, so in essence the file write is useless.  I tried to implement a file read but together with `mutex` and `rake task`, it gets really confusing.  Any pointers will help here.

```
class Customer
  @@customers_to_licenses_hash = nil
  @@last_updated_at = nil
  @@mutex = Mutex.new

  CUSTOMERS_LICENSES_FILE = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/customers_licenses"

  def self.cached_license_with_customer(customer)
    Rails.cache.fetch('customer') {self.license_with_customer(customer)}
  end

  def self.license_with_customer(customer)
    @@mutex.synchronize do
      license = @@customers_to_licenses_hash[customer]
      if license
        return license
      elsif(@@customers_to_licenses_hash.nil? || Time.now.utc - @@last_updated_at > 1.hours)
        updated = self.update_set_customers_licenses
        return @@customers_to_licenses_hash[customer] if updated
      else
        return nil
      end
    end
  end

  def self.update_set_customers_licenses
    updated = nil
    file_write = File.open(CUSTOMERS_LICENSES_FILE, 'w')
    results = self.get_active_customers_licenses
    if results
      @@customers_to_licenses_hash = results
      file_write.print(results.to_json)
      @@last_updated_at = Time.now.utc
      updated = true
    end
    file_write.close
    updated
  end

  def self.get_active_customers_licenses
    #http get thru api
    #return hash of records
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty it's the case that every time rails loads, the environment is "fresh" and has no concept of "state" in between instances. That is to say, a mutex in one ruby instance (the one request to rails) has no effect on a second ruby instance (another request to rails or in this case, a rake task).

If you follow the data upstream, you'll find that the common root of every instance that can be used to synchronize them is the database. You could use [transactional blocks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) or maybe a manual flag you set and unset in the database.